# Globbing in find command

Tags: regex, grep, find, glob

I have an `Android` project in which I have `strings.xml` and other `.xml` files defined in various places depending upon language and other criteria.
There are directories like -

> ```
> > /res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml 
> > /res/values-es-rUS/strings.xml
> > /res/values-fi/strings.xml 
> > /res/values-it/strings.xml
> > /res/values-ms/strings.xml 
> > /res/values-bn/strings.xml
> > /res/values-da/strings.xml
> > /overlay_dir/TN_KOR_COMMON/res/values/strings.xml
> > /overlay_dir/TN_KOR_COMMON/res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml
> > /overlay_dir/TN_KOR_COMMON/res/values-ko/strings.xml
> > /overlay_dir/TN_JPN_COMMON/res/values-ja/strings.xml
> > /res/layout/hovering.xml
> > /res/xml/settings_menu.xml
> ```

Now, I want to find a string in only files in directories which have paths like `/res/values-en-rUS` and `/res/xml`.
I used the command -

```
grep -i "hovering_msg" `find -path "*@(values-en-rUS|xml)*" -iname "*.xml"`
```

but it doesn't seem to work. According to my understanding `*@(values-en-rUS|xml)*"` means find a number of characters followed by either `values-en-rUS` or `xml` followed by any number of characters. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: which shell do you have? bash?

Comment: @Kent yes, the shell is bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you worked in bash env.
You have used `extend globbing`, so you have to turn it on first by:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And for your task, you don't have to combine `grep` and `find`, you can do:

```
grep -i 'pattern' /res/@(values-en-rUS|xml)/*.xml
```

For source codes searching, I recommend ag (silver searcher).

Comment: This does not give me any match.

Comment: @yadav_vishal it worked here, with bash... I just gave it a test. :) you executed `shopt -s extglob` first, didn't you?

Comment: Yeah I did that, not exactly what I was looking for but when I gave some path before /res/@.... like - 
grep -i 'pattern' /..../.../res/@(values-en-rUS|xml)/*.xml, it gives me some matches.

Comment: I looked [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing), but still am confused with pattern and globs, would be helpful if you could point to some references.

Comment: you need let `grep` know which dir should it scan. say, if you have `/foo/bar/res/yourproject` , you gave `/foo/bar/res/@(....)/*.xml` grep starts from `/foo/bar/res/` if you go to `res/` by `cd /foo/bar/res`, make it your current dir, you can `grep 'xyz' @(value...|xml)/*.xml`. I think it's pretty basic stuff.  I am not sure if this answers your question though. @yadav_vishal

Comment: That's not what I meant, I know how `grep` and `find` work. I am confused that sometimes we use patterns and sometimes glob.

Comment: @yadav_vishal the article you referenced is good I think, if you want to know some shoptions regarding glob, this may give some info too: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

Comment: @yadav_vishal as I mentioned in answer, give `ag` a try, it is really fast for source codes searching. also you can set path patterns (in/exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching against the directory part with `-path` or `-regex` is possible as well but it would be simpler to just specify both target directories than trying to match patterns against them. This would save execution time since it wouldn't try to search files in other directories.

```
find /res/values-en-rUS /res/xml -iname '*.xml'
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -i "hovering_msg" `find /res/values-en-rUS /res/xml -iname '*.xml'`
```

Besides splittng output of command substitution with backquotes, it is also be possible to use `while read` from a pipe to also allow spaces in filenames:

```
find /res/values-en-rUS /res/xml -iname '*.xml' | while read file; do
    grep -i "hovering_msg" "$file"
done
```

If you're in a Linux box, using `xargs` would be the better option:

```
find /res/values-en-rUS /res/xml -iname '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -d '\n' -- grep -i "hovering_msg" --
```

Comment: he said he want to do something on an "android **project**", not on an android box. :-)

Comment: @konsolebox The project is present in my linux box and the shell is bash. Also, I don't just have 2 such patterns (values-en-rUS and xml) there are many more.

Comment: @konsolebox /values-en-rUS and /xml are not absolute paths, these are patterns within the path, hence I used globbing.